# Difference between decision tree and rule based reasoner

Tags: terminology, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

I am new to this topic, and in some scientific papers I've been reading about prediction in sports I encountered the term rule based reasoner. Is it this term the same as a semantic reasoner( where the two main directions are forward and backwards chaining?). If yes, can you point out the difference between a decision tree and this? Because for me, it seems pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

Decision tree classifiers could be easily converted to rule based classifiers in data mining and vice Versa. please have a look at "[Introduction to Data Mining](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/index.php)", chapters 4 and 5.

Usually it depends on the data characteristics, how to choose between these two methods and which of the mentioned methods give you smaller classification errors.